# Text Justification / Word Wrap dp problem.Unable to find the overlapping condition in my recursion?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Que:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap

**What I tried & issue faced:** I tried a recursive approach to solve this problem. Currently, unable to find the overlapping subproblems. Can anyone help me how can I optimize, memoize and modify/update my recursion approach?. (I am thinking my approach is Wrong)

**approach:** Either the word is in the current line(if and only if space is left) or will be in the new line.

**Code Flow:**

```
Input text = "Cat is on Floor" .
I stored len in an array = [3,2,2,5]

ans(a,b,c) : a: index, b: line (currently no use), c: current line sum

base condn if all elements are over a>=size: return pow(spaceleft,2)

will return min( subproblem(word in current line),subproblem(word in new line)+pow(spaceleft,2))


Initially :     ans(1,1,3)
          ans(2,1,6)     ans(2,2,2)
      ans(3,2,2)      ans(3,2,5)  ans(3,3,2)
      ans(4,3,5)      ans(4,3,5)  ans(4,4,5)
```

The below code is in python3.x :

```
n=6
arr=[3,2,2,5]
size = 4
def ans(a,b,c):
    if(a>=size):
        return pow((n-c),2);
    if(c+arr[a]+1 > n):
        return (pow((n-c),2)+ans(a+1,b+1,arr[a]))
    return (min(ans(a+1,b,c+arr[a]+1),pow((n-c),2)+ans(a+1,b+1,arr[a])))
print(ans(1,1,3))
```

Thanks in advance for giving your valuable time and helping me....

Comment: I know there are many solutions available on the internet, but I want to find out the problem in my logic

Comment: Please clarify the question you are asking.

Comment: @itprorh66 Currently, I am unable to find the overlapping subproblems.(means I can't apply Dp here) .  So, I want if my approach/Logic is wrong then why is wrong. Also, what updates are required to make it correct.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start or what updates are required?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer.  Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your formulation might be missing some cases. It surely is hard to understand. Here's one that seems to get the right answer.

```
class LineWrapper:
  def __init__(self, lens, width):
    self.lens = lens
    self.width = width;

  def cost(self, ptr=0, used=0):
    remaining = self.width - used

    # Case 1: No words: Cost is due to partially used line.
    if ptr == len(self.lens):
      return remaining ** 2 if used else 0

    # Case 2: First word of line. Must skip.
    if used == 0:
      return self.cost(ptr + 1, self.lens[ptr])

    # Case 3: Out of space. Must wrap.
    needed = 1 + self.lens[ptr]
    if remaining < needed:
      return remaining ** 2 + self.cost(ptr)

    # Case 4: Min cost of skip and wrap.
    return min(self.cost(ptr + 1, used + needed), remaining ** 2 + self.cost(ptr))
```

There's lots of overlap among subproblems in this formulation, and yours, too.  A simple example is [1, 1, 1, 1] with a width of 7.  The solution will try putting this on all combinations of 1, 2, 3, and 4 lines. May sub-combinations will repeat.

To see this more obviously, we can memoize and check for hits:

```
  def memo_cost(self, ptr=0, used=0):
    args = (ptr, used)
    print(args)
    if args in self.memos:
      print(f'Memo hit: {args}')
      return self.memos[args]

    remaining = self.width - used

    # Case 1: No words has cost of partially used line
    if ptr == len(self.lens):
      r = remaining ** 2 if used else 0
      self.memos[args] = r
      print(f'Done: {r}')
      return r

    # Case 2: First word of line. Must skip.
    if used == 0:
      r = self.memo_cost(ptr + 1, self.lens[ptr])
      self.memos[args] = r
      print(f'Must skip: {r}')
      return r
   
    # Case 3: Out of space. Must wrap.
    needed = 1 + self.lens[ptr]
    if remaining < needed:
      r = remaining ** 2 + self.memo_cost(ptr)
      self.memos[args] = r
      print(f'Must wrap: {r}')
      return r

    # Case 4: Min cost of skip wrap and wrap.
    r = min(remaining ** 2 + self.memo_cost(ptr), self.memo_cost(ptr + 1, used + needed))
    self.memos[args] = r
    print(f'Min: {r}')
    return r

print(LineWrapper([1, 1, 1, 1], 7).memo_cost())
```

When run, this produces:

```
$ python3 lb.py
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 0)
(3, 1)
(3, 0)
(4, 1)
Done: 36
Must skip: 36
(4, 3)
Done: 16
Min: 16
Must skip: 16
(3, 3)
(3, 0)
Memo hit: (3, 0)
(4, 5)
Done: 4
Min: 4
Min: 4
Must skip: 4
(2, 3)
(2, 0)
Memo hit: (2, 0)
(3, 5)
(3, 0)
Memo hit: (3, 0)
(4, 7)
Done: 0
Min: 0
Min: 0
Min: 0
Must skip: 0
0
```

Comment: thank you very much... self.memos= {} is missing in init method .. actually i made a mistake i didn't spend much time on it.. my approach is also correct after looking your implementation I figured that my dp 2D array should have a,c as parameters (mistake : I never considered c alone will be helpful ..  thought that current c is not helpful for my suffixes). Thank you very much ...  @gene

Comment: I have added  the updated code .. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

My answer with memo thanks to @Gene

```python3
    n=7
    arr=[3,2,2,5]
    INF = 9223372036854775807
    size = 4
    dp = [[INF for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(size+1)]
    def ans(a,b,c):
        if(dp[a][c]!=INF):
            return dp[a][c]
        if(a>=size):
            dp[a][c] = pow((n-c),2)
            return pow((n-c),2)
        if(c+arr[a]+1 > n):
            dp[a][c] = (pow((n-c),2)+ans(a+1,b+1,arr[a]))
            return dp[a][c]
        dp[a][c] = (min(ans(a+1,b,c+arr[a]+1),pow((n-c),2)+ans(a+1,b+1,arr[a])))
        return dp[a][c]
    print(ans(1,1,3))
```

Comment: I think there's still a mistake here. If all the input has been used, but c is zero, then the entire line is blank. An unused line has cost zero.

Comment: thanks @Gene .. Maybe I am wrong but c will never be 0 in my case until you pass 0 in an array...small proof/justification to my statement : if len =1 then c =1 , if len =k then c=k .. now what I am doing is saying the word is in the current line or in the next line in both the cases c>0 as the word length is greater than 0 ... but  I will have to think about if user added multiple spaces in b/w the text.

Comment: Actually I tried your test case [1,1,1,1] 7 (it's working) and my some cases too.